# How to know whether √(x-y)² is right or √(y-x)² is right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

sin⁻¹x + sin⁻¹y = sin⁻¹{x√(1-y²) + y√(1-x²)}                                                                           2sin⁻¹x =sin⁻¹{2x√(1-x²)}                                         3sin⁻¹x = 2sin⁻¹x + sin⁻¹x                 ⇒sin⁻¹{2x√(1-x²)}+ sin⁻¹x                          y=2x√(1-x²)  x=x                                ⇒sin⁻¹[x√(1-{2x√(1-x²)}²+2x√(1-x²)√(1-x²)]
⇒ sin⁻¹[x√(1-2(2x²)+(2x²)²)+ 2x - 2x³]      ⇒sin⁻¹[x√({2x²-1}²)+ 2x - 2x³]
⇒sin⁻¹[x{2x²-1}+ 2x - 2x³]                       ⇒sin⁻¹[x]             This is clearly wrong.  But I dont understand why is this wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Could you please use Mathjax in your posts? It's easier to read. Here you have a nice tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Remember that $\sqrt{u^2} = \color{red}{|}u\color{red}{|}$ for all real $u$ (absolute value sign required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt{(x-y)^2}=\sqrt{(y-x)^2}=\mid  x-y  \ \mid $$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\sqrt{(x-y)^2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2(y-x)^2}=\sqrt{(y-x)^2}$$